# AKKA HTTP PathMatcher simplify

Tags: akka-http

Many of you seen this thing:

```
val route: Route = get {
  pathPrefix("hello" / String) { name =>
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      complete(s"Hello! $name")
    }     
  }
}
```

i want a little simplify it, like this:

```
val route: Route = get {
  pathWithEndOrSlash("hello" / String) { name =>
    complete(s"Hello! $name")
  }
}
```

how i can do this?

Comment: Have you tried `path("hello" / String /.?) { name => ...`?

Comment: error - ')' expected but '.' found